# find_package(CURL REQUIRED) found missing library. Why?

Tags: c++, cmake, libcurl

I am trying to write some simple program that uses libcurl. I am using CLion editor with Mingw-16.1. 
In my attempts i decided to change version of the libcurl, and deleted it from mingw. After that, i have tried to reload cmake on my project, but it founds libcurl that i have already deleted.

CMakeList.txt

```
find_package(CURL REQUIRED)
if(CURL_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "Found CURL version: ${CURL_VERSION_STRING}")
    message(STATUS "Using CURL include dir(s): ${CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
    message(STATUS "Using CURL lib(s): ${CURL_LIBRARIES}")
    include_directories(${CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
else()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find CURLLL")
endif()
```

And rusult

```
Found CURL version: 
-- Using CURL include dir(s): C:/MinGW/include
-- Using CURL lib(s): C:/MinGW/lib/libcurl.lib
```

But there is no such files in MinGW library. I have already deleted libcurl. I am missing something. Can you help me?

Comment: Does deleting the whole cmake build directory and rerun cmake helps?

Comment: and delete CMakeCache.txt

Comment: Yeah deleting CMakeCache.txt helps. Thanks!